# Display math symbols in Ext.js / Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I'm looking for a way to display math symbols and equations (coming from Latex e.g.) in Ext.js / Sencha Touch UI-Components (specifically buttons and textfields). I grasp that "ext.draw.component" might be a good starting point to develop something appropriate. Is there another way to display math? What would be your choice? Anyone came up with a solution for a similar problem already?

Any advice appreciated.
Best regards,
Thomas

Comment: I guess I would use a math font, with some CSS. If you use ext.draw.component you need to use the GPL version. And if you use that it would be interesting to open source your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you all you want to do is display mathematical symbols / equations, then you could just use a separate library like [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/).
You output the thing you want to display in one of the supported formats (LaTeX, MathML etc) and it converts it for you

Comment: Hi dkwarr87! Thanks for the suggestion. Do you think it will be possible to deliver mathjax via phonegap in a mobile application?