# Sencha Touch and MathJax

Tags: extjs, mathjax

I am trying to display math-equations in a Sencha view component (extends: Ext.Container), using a Ext.Label Component and MathJax JS. (As was suggested answering my other question: [Display math symbols in Ext.js / Sencha Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26587012/display-math-symbols-in-ext-js-sencha-touch?noredirect=1#comment41792354_26587012))

This is the initialization of the view component:

```
Ext.define('TIQuiz3.view.Question', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
...
requires: ['Ext.Label', ...],


config: {
    fullscreen: true,
    ...
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    }
},

initialize: function() {
    this.callParent();
    ...
    var questionLabel = {
        xtype: 'label',
        style: {
            'border':'1px solid black',
            'background':'white'
        },
        margin: 10,
        padding: 10,
        html: "<div>Es sei $L = \{011, 01, 11, 100\}$ \"uber dem Alphabet $\Sigma = \{0,1\}$.</div>",
        flex: 1
    };
    ...
    this.add([...,questionLabel,...]);

}
```

I have included a local copy of MathJAX in the app.json file:

```
"js": [
    {
        "path": "touch/sencha-touch.js",
        "x-bootstrap": true
    },
    {
        "path": "bootstrap.js",
        "x-bootstrap": true
    },
    {
        "path": "resources/mathjax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML",
        "update": "delta"
    },
    {
        "path": "app.js",
        "bundle": true,  /* Indicates that all class dependencies are concatenated into this file when build */
        "update": "delta"
    }
],
```

MathJax indicates to be loaded successfully.

But the output of the label does not display math properly. Instead it simply looks like this:

> Es sei $L = {011, 01, 11, 100}$ "uber dem Alphabet $Sigma = {0,1}$.

Is displaying math with MathJax and HTML possible using a Sencha Label Component?

Any advice appreciated!

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: Urgs... Deleted my comment accidentally. Could you confirm this is not just because $ are not default delimiter in MathJax? I.e., have you tried \\(...\\) or \[...\] for display style?

Comment: Confirmed, thanks for your comment. I have tried \\(...\\) and I have added $ as default inline delimiter in the used config file. I have also tried using block math. Furthermore I figured that I have to use double \\ since in JS strings interprete \ as escape character. None of this worked.

Comment: Great. Is it perhaps a timing issue? I.e. do you call MathJax to typeset after content arrives in the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks Peter, that brought me to the solution.

The problem was indeed the rendering of the content after the onload-event of the page.

For these cases MathJax holds a method to invoke the typesetting manually at a later time. So what I did was adding the following afterPainted-Listener to the rendered view component:

```
listeners : {
  order : 'after',
  painted : function() {
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
  }
}
```

Note that, as Peter pointed out, in order for the upper to work one has to configure $ to be accepted as math delimiter from MathJax - which is not default behaviour.

Thanks for the advice!